# How to delete master branch on remote?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am trying to delete the 'master' branch on remote. Note: **I am not trying to delete the local master branch but the master branch on the remote**.

The command is

```
git push origin master --delete
```

The error I receive is:

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To my:shared/pop.team/pop.TallyWorld
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'my:shared/pop.team/pop.TallyWorld'
```

I am currently **not on master** branch.

Also, I don't want any default branch for the repo. Is it possible?

Kindly suggest a solution to delete the master branch on remote.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: Since the working directory is clean(no unstaged changes); git status does not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to tell exactly what to do. It seems like for reasons unknown to us, `git` likes to call `master` the "current" branch (though there really should be no concept of "current" on a bare remote; nevertheless, `HEAD` points to `master` on a remote in the default configuration (and I have no idea if there are circumstances where this could be otherwise)).

```
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
```

Also, deleting `master` seems to have the desired effect of not checking out anything on clone:

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
```